# Помогите пожалуйста дописать код что бы в библиотеке leaflet считивались координаты маркера

Tags: javascript

Передо мной стала цель сделать карту ввовда координат в базу через карту. Я нашел хорошую библиотеку leaflet. И правил код. Заставил маркер перемещаться. Но надо что бы при появлении маркера и при перетаскивании маркера считивались координаты. Маркер должен быть только один и при появлении другого первый удаляеться (в этом коде так всё и работает). Помогите пожалуйста с координатами что бы я мог их считивать. Вот код скрипта:

```js
// Initialize the map and assign it to a variable for later use var map = L.map('map', { // Set latitude and longitude of the map center (required) center: [37.7833, -122.4167], // Set the initial zoom level, values 0-18, where 0 is most zoomed-out (required) zoom: 10 });

L.control.scale().addTo(map);

// Create a Tile Layer and add it to the map //var tiles = new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map); L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors' }).addTo(map);

var searchControl = new L.esri.Controls.Geosearch().addTo(map);

var results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

searchControl.on('results', function(data){ results.clearLayers(); for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng, {draggable: true}));

}

});

setTimeout(function(){$('.pointer').fadeOut('slow' );},3400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот я с этого проекта брал код https://codepen.io/exomark/pen/dafBD

```
    // Initialize the map and assign it to a variable for later use
var map = L.map('map', {
    // Set latitude and longitude of the map center (required)
    center: [37.7833, -122.4167],
    // Set the initial zoom level, values 0-18, where 0 is most zoomed-out (required)
    zoom: 10
});

L.control.scale().addTo(map);

// Create a Tile Layer and add it to the map
//var tiles = new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  var searchControl = new L.esri.Controls.Geosearch().addTo(map);

  var results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

  searchControl.on('results', function(data){
    results.clearLayers();
    for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
    }
  });

setTimeout(function(){$('.pointer').fadeOut('slow');},3400);
```

Может так легче будет понять меня.
Мне надо что бы при появлении маркера и при его перемещении считивались координаты.
Поможете?